# What is [this, self] before handler assignment means in Boost library asio example?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-asio

I have never seen such syntax before "[this, self]", I used to program C and did a bit with C++, and now learning C++11 and Boost library, the compiler is happy with, but I can't figure out how it works and what it does.

```
void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
---------^
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_write(length);
          }
        });
  }
```

It comes from Boost library Async Echo server example in [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the *capture-list* of the lambda. It is capturing the variable `this` (pointer) and the variable `self` declared one line above.

```
    [...](...){...}
//    A    B    C
```

The above is simplified syntax for the lambda in your code. `A` is the capture-list mentioned above (used to "capture" variables from the current scope). `B` is the argument list (just like in a function) and `C` is the body (again, like a function).

Comment: Aha, never heard of Lambda functions before, I'm googling it now and the first impression it is something like anonymous functions in say javascript. But it seems more complex than that, interesting feature in C++11.

Answer (score -1):

This lambda capture in order to make sure the session object outlives the asynchronous operation: as long as the lambda is alive.